# In buildroot, how to enable deprecated features?

Tags: mips, cross-compiling, instruction-set, buildroot

I have to compile C for mips that uses MIPS1 instruction set, but Buildroot no longer supports MIPS1 instruction set (See the bottom of this page: http://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html).

Could you please let me know how to enable the deprecated feature (i.e., MIPS1 instruction set) in Buildroot?

Any comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build options -> Show packages that are deprecated or obsolete

Which platform are you working with? It is really strange that you need MIPS1 support.

Comment: my HOST OS is linux running on Intel 80386, and target OS is embedded linux running on MIPS R3000. "readelf" command showed that binary programs running on target OS have [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909788/meanings-of-mips-flags-from-readelf-command) flags.

Comment: I also have a router which kernel is compiled for MIPS1 and identify its processor as R3000, though it's apparently not. Thus I needed this too. Thanks.